# How to validate DMN syntactically using VS Code DMN editor /kogito Bundle?

Tags: validation, drools, dmn

I was using Drools Business central and whenever I use to modify DMN file , used to leverage validate option to check the DMN . Since Drools 8 , Business central is retired so I started leveraging VS Code plugins , I am unable to find an option to validate DMN . Hence until I don't run DMN I don't know what is the problem .
I am using DMN Editor plugin v0.26.0 , VSCode v1.66 and kogito bundle plugin v0.28.2 .

I didnt find any options to validate on VSCode editor .

Answer (score 0):

Since Drools v7, we have offered the `kie-dmn-validation` [module](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/main/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-validation). This is the validation capability you are likely referring to as using from Business Central, you can use the standard wiring we provide for this capability as out-of-the-box, or you can roll your own usage.

In Drools v7 and v8, when your project is a KJAR, the `kie-maven-plugin` will ensure the DMN validation is performed; after ensuring you are using standard KJAR project (such as those from BC) as explained in the [Drools manual](https://www.drools.org/learn/documentation.html), you can tune the validation options of the maven plugin with:

- v7: https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#dmn-validation-con_dmn-models
- v8: https://docs.drools.org/8.38.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/DMN/index.html#dmn-validation-con_dmn-models

You likely want to ensure the VS Code IDE instance you are using is leveraging the Maven build, so that the `kie-maven-plugin` will be used per details linked above.

Finally, if you are using the [KIE Sandbox](https://sandbox.kie.org), the validation is part of the KIE Extended Services running locally.

Comment: I should also add the validation goes beyond syntax to semantic validation. Fun fact: semantic rules are defined in DRL for the curious 

Comment: I have a faulty DMN ( one of the Literal FEEL expression syntax is incorrect  , but it still adheres to DMN schema ) . If i import this DMN to Business central instance , it immediately validates the syntax of literal expression and shows the problems in Error window .  While if i use maven plugin and compile the project which has this schema ,it doesnt complain .   My question is - how can i achieve that without using Business central as it is retired effective version 8 .

Comment: sample DMN section below :<dmn:literalExpression id="_D0EF7199-3833-4FBA-BF18-2A57A0F8BC76">
      <dmn:text>if (true) then {
  reasonCdTmp: if(Domain1.attr1="0000" then "0001" else "0002"
  result: {"reasonCode":reasonCdTmp,"sum":calcSum()}
}.result
</dmn:text>
    </dmn:literalExpression>

Comment: about:
> "_While if i use maven plugin and compile the project which has this schema ,it doesnt complain_"

sounds like a misconfiguration of the maven project on your end; consider sharing a reproducer on the drools community forums so to take a look with more details